# Show that the following polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, rational-numbers

Show that the following polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$:

$x^7 + 28x^2 + 32x + 6$

I know how to use the Eisenstein's Criterion method and testing with roots.
The problem is that I can't use the methods here

For Eisenstein's Criterion I need a leading polynomial of degree higher than $1$

For the root method I need a polynomial of degree $2$ or $3$.

How can I solve the problem and what is the name of the method I should use?

Comment: Use *Eisenstein's* criterion. Also please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Eisenstein works in its current form.  The degree of this polynomial is $7$ which is certianly $>1$.

Comment: i have a bit trouble with this condition for example if p = 2: p does not divide a_n. Everything can you divide 1 with

Comment: oh, i understand it now, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply Eisenstein's Criterion with $p = 2$ to the polynomial $$\color{red}{1} x^7 + \color{blue}{28}x^2 + \color{blue}{32}x + \color{green}6$$

We need to check that

- $2 \not \mid \color{red}1$
- $2 \mid \color{blue}{28}$
- $2 \mid \color{blue}{32}$
- $2 \mid \color{green}{6}$ and $2^2 \not\mid \color{green}{6}$

Comment: Thanks that helped alot :)